# Reconnecting graphql subscription

Tags: apollo-client, graphql-ws

I am using apollo client and graphql-ws library for subscription.

I have the following requirement. Server redeploys every morning and that time the existing subscription gets completed. I need to reconnect when the service is up which is not happening.

I have tried setInterval onComplete but that will start calling until we have data and can lead to multiple subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do would be to set the [retry-related options for `graphql-ws`](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/ws/docs/interfaces/client.ClientOptions#retryattempts).

That way it will look just like a running connection to your application and it reconnects internally.

Comment: Already done that. retryAttempts 10 is set. During deployent seems like the socket connection gets closed, not sure what reconnect logic to apply